# Awesomium .NET: Inspector Size Issue

Tags: .net, awesomium

I want to use the remote debugging functionality from Awesomium .NET 1.7.5 but the Awesomium Inspector window displays the dev-tools so small in height that can hardly be used. Most of the space is white. Please see the attached image:

[image: inspector with size issue]

Is there a way to overcome this issue? Tested with chrome 39.0.2171.95. (I realized also that the inspector does not work with Internet Explorer and Firefox at all.)

The following error messages are displayed in the chrome dev tools:

```
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js (index):55
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js (index):56 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js (index):57 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js (index):58 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js (index):59 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js (index):60 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js (index):61 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js (index):62 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js (index):63 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js (index):64 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js (index):65 
GET http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js 
jquery.js:4 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:2222/".
Request with id = 6 failed. [object Object] InspectorBackend.js:237 
 Request with id = 18 failed. [object Object] InspectorBackend.js:237
```

As a workaround you can manually change the height of the div tag with class "row-fluid" after you have chosen your application to debug to a value you wish:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="height: 500px;">
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what changed for this to start happening? It definitely didn't use to happen, but now I'm seeing it too.

Answer (score 1):

After much Googling, we came across [http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/5936/inspector-frame-height-only-150-pixels-high.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20160525034801/http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/5936/inspector-frame-height-only-150-pixels-high.html) – in short, this bug cropped up in Chrome >=39, and can be hacked fixed by editing the CSS in inspector.pak then stripping whitespace until the checksum matches again, crazy!

Comment: Following the instructions there had no effect. The layout is also wrong in Firefox btw.

Comment: I found my install caches the pak file heavily – I have no idea where, or how to clear that cache – but it did fix it for other users. Also, I am not sure the remote inspector ever worked in FF anyway?

Comment: No it does not work in FF, but you can still see a page defunct page with wrong CSS (So the style issue is not limited to Chrome).

Comment: So it is about finding the cache. I will try to find it.

Comment: Solid effort spending 3 months looking though ;)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @AndersLindén Awesomium project is dead and their website is offline. I changed the link so it points to an entry of the web archive. Not the most recent version, but good enough. I would anyway suggest not to use Awesomium. It is totally outdated, the company stopped the product, it's not open-source.